# After delay() is called on a celery task, it takes more than 5 to 10 seconds for the tasks to even start executing with redis as the server

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, redis, celery

I have Redis as my Cache Server. When I call delay() on a task,it takes more than 10 tasks to even start executing. Any idea how to reduce this unnecessary lag?
Should I replace Redis with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to say what the cause of the delay is without being able to inspect your application and server logs, but I can reassure you that the delay is not normal and not an effect specific to either Celery or using Redis as the broker. I've used this combination a lot in the past and execution of tasks happens in a number of milliseconds.

I'd start by ensuring there are no network related issues between your client creating the tasks, your broker (Redis) and your task consumers (celery workers).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know if there are any network related issues.

Comment: My redis server was not enabled to run at startup and hence I guess celery was restarting the server again and again which was taking the time. I stopped my redis server, restarted it and now the tasks are executed within a fraction of time. Thanks very much for your time!!